# How to push a CouchDB image to heroku-container-registry

Tags: docker, heroku, couchdb, containers

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM klaemo/couchdb:latest
```

It is said that this image exposes the port 5984, however, Heroku does not allow to customize the port listening, how can I map the two ports $PORT:5984 or how can I push a CouchDB image to Heroku.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok do you have docker repository in heroku-container-registry ?